# Using Fluent.NHibernate, how can I do an Insert based on a Select statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, fluent-nhibernate, iqueryable

I have a fairly complex piece of logic that generates a `IQueryable` for me that I use to return data from my database using `Fluent.NHibernate`.

However, I need to be able to store the results of this query back into the database (just the primary keys really but that is kind of a side issue)

How can I generate an insert statement based on the `IQueryable` I already have to get SQL like the example below generated:

```
INSERT INTO MySavedResults (Id, FirstName, LastName)
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Member
WHERE 
FirstName = 'John' and LastName ='Snow' and ...-- more conditions
```

Comment: Maybe NH way, using  session.CreateSQLQuery(your_query)

Comment: I considered that, but that would imply having to duplicate the logic I already have. So was hoping to avoid re-creating the SQL myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to do this directly in NHibernate without using raw sql.

You can of course use the `IQueryable` you already have and generate nhibernate entities from this `IQueryable`.  You can then take these entities and use a combination of `IStatelessSession` and batching to improve performance for large result sets.

Here is a good example of this:

[Speed up bulk insert operations with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943967/speed-up-bulk-insert-operations-with-nhibernate)

I would also look at the other answers for additional speed improvements.

### Edit:

Another possible way that this could be done would be to convert the linq query to raw sql using something like this:

[How can I have NHibernate only generate the SQL without executing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704462/how-can-i-have-nhibernate-only-generate-the-sql-without-executing-it)

Take the raw sql and prepend it with the insert statement you want to create and execute this sql using something like this:

[Executing Sql statements with Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852720/executing-sql-statements-with-fluent-nhibernate)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing now. Was hoping for a more effective solution. Starting to think I'm going to have to write an NHibernate extension.

Comment: Just a note that speed isn't my issue. It is disk IO usage killing everything else my DB is going.

Comment: @DanielvanHeerden Made another edit.  Didn't realize you were already doing this.

Comment: Mmm,  I'll have a look. I believe the SQL generated is in a paramerized format. Which is why I haven't tried this approach before.  Will give it a go and let you know.

Comment: I have converted this sql before from parameterized to non-parameterized for logging purposes.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015005/execute-nhibernate-generated-prepared-statements-in-sql-server-management-studio/